# The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 5 parameters were supplied

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, 4d-database

I am trying to insert data into a 4D database using pyodbc driver. I am able to connect and get data that i prevoiusly inserted using the same format. Here is the code:

```
#Connection string
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={4d v20 ODBC Driver 64-bit};SERVER=127.0.0.1;UID=Designer;PWD=123456') # This works
        self.curs = self.conn.cursor()



#Function
feed_analysis_data = (data.dateArrivedLab, user_id, data.labAnalysisID, data.feedName, data.harvestDate)
        
        
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO feed_analysis (date, user_id, lab_analysis_id, feed_name, date_harvested) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        try:
            self.curs.execute(sql_query, feed_analysis_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error executing SQL query:", e)
```

I have checked the inserted data, all the parameters are present there.

I have tried using %s, ?, '?', :1... as parameter markers but i still get the same error message: Error executing SQL query: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 5 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

I have searched online and here at SO, but none of the things i found works for what i am encountering. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `?` is the correct parameter marker for pyodbc. The code you've written should work.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? The indentation is off. You would get that error if you put the `?` inside quotes in the SQL.

Comment: Yeah, the indentation for the feed analysis data is incorrect in the example, first time posting so i probably made a mistake when copying. Its correct in the code. I have no idea why this code dont work. Will update if i figure something out.

Comment: I tried to insert a test user into the user table, and i was able to query it. Modified the query with the exact same parameter markers (i only changed the data and table/column names) and i got the same error as before. Something about this query does not make sense.

Comment: When you changed the column names, did you change the number of columns? Make sure the number of `?` and length of `feed_analysis_data` still match.

Comment: Make sure you're using ASCII `?` characters, not some other Unicode character that looks similar.

Comment: I did not change the parameter markers or number of columns. Only table and column names. I created a test table to try and insert the data into that with the exact same data and column names, and i was able to do it. So I'm gonna try to delete and remake the table to see if maybe the table is the problem.

Comment: This error happens when parsing the query, the table structure should be irrelevant.